# is it possible to save metadata about mdf file inside the file?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I would like to save metedata about the database such as version, creation date, etc.

Is it possible to save it in the mdf file itself so I can get it using the DataContext object?

If it's not possible, where/what is the best way to save my data about the database?

Comment: Of course you may create another table and store whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[Extended properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx)" can be attached to any object in a database, including the database itself. However, it is simple text

You'd simply have a table called "Version" or such to capture what you need, which can then be accessed like a user table. This can also be used for reporting etc